# How is value for content_type_id generated in generic foreign key?

Tags: django

I was trying to use generic foreign key for one of my projects, I went through the django documentation, so its basically combination of content_type and object_id.

Now in my table is see that an integer value is generated for content_type_id, so my question is that how is the integer set for the content_type_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a foreign key to the ContentTypes table.

Answer (score 0):

The number is assigned by the contentype framework. You can take a look at this by adding this to your admin.

Add these lines in any of your apps admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
class CTAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('app_label','model', 'id')
admin.site.register(ContentType, CTAdmin)
```

Then you'll see a Contenttype app in your admin and this will show a list of all models and ids.